# Using spread and all function axios does not load class function

Tags: node.js, axios

I am using axios to call 2 endpoints concurrently. I have another function in my class which manipulates the response the endpoints give. But I keep on getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'manipulateData' of null`. unable to figure out why it returns a null object.

Below is my code on how I am using

```
class testData {
  //constructor 
  async getData(){
    await this.token
    let options = {
      method : 'get',
      url : 'url',
      params :{
        deviceid : this.device
      }
    }

    axios.all([
      axios(options),
      axios.get(url2)
    ])
    .then(axios.spread(function(resp1, resp2){
      return this.manipulateData(resp1.data, resp2.data)
    })).catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  manipulateData(data1, data2){
    //do some manipulation
  } 
}
```

Comment: `.then(axios.spread((resp1, resp2) => this.manipulateData(resp1.data, resp2.data)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `this` in your function refers to the Promise resolve callback.

If you use ES you could use the arrow syntax, which would keep `this` to be the class

so change:

```
.then(axios.spread(function(resp1, resp2){
    return this.manipulateData(resp1.data, resp2.data)
}))
```

to:

```
.then(axios.spread((resp1, resp2) => {
    return this.manipulateData(resp1.data, resp2.data)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gijs Beker . That helped me resolve the issue.